# Heartbeat on all the backend servers attached to node-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, heartbeat, node-http-proxy

Does node-http-proxy provide a way to send a hearbeat to all the backend servers attached to it.

If I use the examples/simpler-balancer.js server and specify 2 backend servers, 1 of which is essentially down and the load balancing is set to round robin mode then every alternate request is not served.

Have I missed a setting or this feature is not meant to be part of the module.

Comment: If you just want these features better use something like HAProxy, its  faster and supports what you want.